# ASP.NET Core Web Api and PowerShell Invoke-RestMethod (Method Post) plus ResponseText / ReturnValue / ErrorMessage

Tags: powershell, rest, asp.net-core, webapi

I'm currently developing an ASP.NET Core Web API (v3.1) (plus a PowerShell Script).

The controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class RegisterDeviceController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly SCMDB _context;

    public RegisterDeviceController(SCMDB context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // POST: api/RegisterDevice
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Device>> PostDevice(Device device)
    {
        if (device.SiteKey == null)
            return StatusCode(406,"NoSiteKeyDefined!");
        return null;
    }
}
```

The 'consumer' is a PowerShell script:

```
# Post to web api
try{
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$ScmWebApiUrl" -Method Post -Body $JsonString -ContentType "application/json"
    }
    catch {
        $err = $_.Exception
    }

Write-Host $ErrResp
```

What I'm trying to figure out is: how to get the ResponseText "NoSiteKeyDefined!" in PowerShell.

I get:

```
[DBG]: PS C:\Windows\system32>> $err.Message
The remote server returned an error: (406) Not Acceptable.
```

But I also need the Message (in this case -> NoSiteKeyDefined!)

It doesn't have to be a 406 error code, it can also be another 'ActionResult' or response. I also tried it return BadRequest("NoSiteKeyDefined!") but I don't find this piece of message neither in the $response nor in the $err object. The important thing is that I can pass a message that can be received and processed in the PowerShell script.

Comment: how's your `$JsonString` looks like?, can you watch it's value in the debug in VS?

Comment: @Avshalom: basically the $JsonString is not relevant. The only thing that has relevance is the $response or maybe the $_.Exception -> that's what PowerShell gets/receives from the REST API.

Answer (score 0):

> What I'm trying to figure out is: how to get the ResponseText "NoSiteKeyDefined!" in PowerShell

I can reproduce same issue if accessing from `Exception` property with `$_.Exception` that includes detailed message of WebException.

To get the value `'NoSiteKeyDefined!'` we set, we can access it by using `Write-Host $_` directly, like below.

```
try{
    $ScmWebApiUrl = 'https://xxxx/api/RegisterDevice'

    $Body = @{
         SiteKey = $NULL
    }

    $JsonString = $Body | ConvertTo-Json

    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$ScmWebApiUrl"  -Method Post -Body $JsonString -ContentType 'application/json'
}
catch{
    Write-Host $_
    Write-Host $_.Exception
}
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: interresting finding. I can not reproduce it. What PowerShell Version are you using? Can you post details about your $PSVersionTable? My PSVersion is: 5.1.18362.752. I'm not using PS .net core, since the script needs to be runnable on a W10 native installation.